# Username should be non-editable after creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

It seems i'm stuck on a simple point here - i have a model called "User" with a field called "username" which is set as unique.

Lets assume a new visitor is on my site, wants to sign up, has to choose a username and clicks then on "Sign up". In this case my field "username" has to be attr_accessible.

What i now want to accomplish is that the field "username" is no longer editable when the user is editing his/her account.

How can i realize this?

Bouns-Karma: I'm using CanCan with devise, so a solution where an user with the admin-role CAN change the username of given user would be supernice! My mind tells me something with "unless user.admin?" but i was on coding-break too long.

Anyway - i hope there will be some answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom validation on update:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :admin_action  # do not put in attr_accessible

  validate :freeze_username, :on => :update

  protected

  def freeze_username
    errors.add(:username, "cannot be changed") if self.username_changed? unless self.admin? || self.admin_action
  end
end
```

`admin_action` is a virtual attribute that you can set to `true` from the controller if an admin is making the update.